# Search data from Excel using textbox and retrieve in DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a Textbox and i want that when we enter something in Textbox ,it will search that data from Excel. Then, all the record from the selected data from excel should appear in DataGridView.
My code only able to get all the records from excel.

```
  Try
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='c:\MECH_1.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unTan.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention Your `textbox` value in Query and use `Like` Command as below..

```
  Try
    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    MyConnection = New 
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source='c:\MECH_1.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from 
    [Sheet1$] where country like '%" & Trim(textbox1.Text) & "%' or Name like '%" & Trim(textbox1.Text) & "%'", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Note :WHERE country LIKE '%or%' Finds any values that have "or" in any position
      WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'  Finds any values that ends with "a"
      WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'  Finds any values that starts with "a"